# Make all "You need at least 2k/3k reputation to review" banners equally wide

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design

The review landing page has received a redesign, and the messages like this:

> You need at least 3k reputation to review reopen votes.

are now shown as banners. However, I'm a bit annoyed because they have different lengths. The one for the Reopen Votes sticks out like a sore thumb:

[image]

but the others have slightly different lengths too. Can this be changed?

Comment: Blame Stacks I guess

Comment: The real solution is to gather 2k on every site

Comment: @JohnDvorak 3k, you mean. Well, [I'm trying to ...](https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel?tab=accounts)

Comment: I do mean 2k. If there's only one banner on the page, there's no inconsistency.

Comment: @JohnDvorak but there are two banners then, one for Close Votes and one for Reopen Votes :)

Comment: ... ah. closevotes and reopen votes both require 3k, and they are different widths. Weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed. The permissions banners that show up for individual queues in the review queues dashboard screen should now have consistent widths.

---

> View All Review Queues.
> An issue with several?
> At least all same width